# Rotating pseudo element cut issue

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I'm trying to rotate a pseudo element, which has a background-image.
As its background is positioned at the center of the main element, for effect purposes, it gets cutted when rotated.

I've created an example, using random images, just to illustrate what I mean.
I'd like to know what's wrong with this approach and why it's getting cutted. Is there any way I could rotate the background without cutting it off?

Thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 'use strict';
 $('button').on('click', () => {
  $("li").addClass('issue-simulation');
 })
});
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
ul li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/180/180);
  background-size: 80%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  transition: 650ms cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.1, 1);
}
ul li:hover:after {
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
ul li.issue-simulation:after {
  background-position: calc(50% + 50px) center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="">
  </li>
</ul>
<button>Simulate issue</button>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this code at the end? `background-position: calc(50% + 50px) center;`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava, it's just to simulate the issue by positioning the background where it is in the real case.

Comment: I'm not seeing any "cutting"...

Comment: I think you should use the `top` and `left` properties to move the pseudo element. The `background` is definitely not going to extend beyond the borders of the pseudo element, so you might observe the 'cutting'.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using background-position instead of `translateX()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is because you are manipulating the `background-position`. You cannot force a background image to overflow its containing parent: that is something that you cannot workaround.

I believe your problem might be an XY problem, because I suppose you ran into issues with compositing/combining transforms. **Something like this will *not* work**:

```
ul li:hover:after {
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
ul li.issue-simulation:after {
  transform: translateX(50px);
}
```

...**because the `transform` property is not additive** (i.e. you cannot combine the `transform` property)

Therefore, a proper solution is actually to use CSS variables:

1. Declare the base appearance

   ```
   :root {
     --rotate: 0deg;
     --translateX: 0;
   }
   ```
2. Apply these variables to the styling of the pseudo-element:

   ```
   ul li:after {
     transform: translateX(var(--translateX)) rotate(var(--rotate));
   }
   ```
3. Then, you use JS to manipulate these CSS variables programmatically:

   ```
   const root = document.documentElement;

    $('ul li')
      .on('mouseover', () => root.style.setProperty('--rotate', '-10deg'))
      .on('mouseout', () => root.style.setProperty('--rotate', '0deg'));

    $('button').on('click', () => root.style.setProperty('--translateX', '50px'))
   ```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const root = document.documentElement;

  $('ul li')
    .on('mouseover', () => root.style.setProperty('--rotate', '-10deg'))
    .on('mouseout', () => root.style.setProperty('--rotate', '0deg'));

  $('button').on('click', () => root.style.setProperty('--translateX', '50px'))
});
```

```css
/* CSS variables */

:root {
  --rotate: 0deg;
  --translateX: 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

ul li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/180/180);
  background-size: 80%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  transition: 650ms cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.1, 1);
  /* Apply `transform` to the actual pseudo-element */
  transform: translateX(var(--translateX)) rotate(var(--rotate));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="">
  </li>
</ul>
<button>Simulate issue</button>
```